# Android Annotations with Kotlin and build tools 2.3.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-annotations

To use Android Annotations prior to 2.3.0 a person would do this:

```
dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

to use Kotlin you would use `kapt` instead of `apt` ([link](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/androidannotations-with-kotlin/2242)).

Since 2.3.0 a person needs to use the annotationProcessor instead of apt:

```
annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
```

Does anyone know what needs to change in order to use Kotlin with the annotationProcessor?

I currently have a very simple, main activity that I set up to use `@EActivity` to grab the layout.  I declared the generated file in the manifest, `.MainActivity_`.

In java, this works fine.  In Kotlin:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   }
}
```

I get a runtime error:

> Process: [...], PID: 10018
>                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{[...].MainActivity_}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "[...].MainActivity_" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/[...]-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/[...]-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

**** UPDATE ****

So I cleaned and rebuilt the project.  It seems annotations isn't generating the underscore file for MainActivity.  Makes sense but I don't know why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `kapt` (and `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`) instead `annotationProcessor` if you want to use Kotlin code for annotation processing (you can continue use annotationProcessor only if you don't generate any code from Kotlin sources, like in your example, where you have MainActivity written in Kotlin)

Comment: Can you point me toward (or provide in your answer) exactly how to set up my gradle files to do that?  I've tried to `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and it says the plugin can't be found?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you have kotlin gradle plugin in your gradle buildscript? You should have `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"` in your `buildscript.dependendencies` block.

More information about kapt - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html

Also, be sure that you applied `kotlin-android` and `kotlin-kapt` plugins to your application module (`app` module by default)

Comment: I appreciate the help!  I've gotten farther, I can build everything with the plugin but I need to tell AA where the manifest is.  I'm using `kapt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}` which is what I used with `apt` (I just changed to `kapt`).  but that's not working.  Error `Error:(48, 0) No such property: processResources for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApkVariantOutputData
<a href="openFile:/[...]/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>`

Comment: Why do you want to pass androidManifestFile to kapt? What do you want to achieve?
I think variants are not ready yet when you configuring kapt, so this is the reason why it doesn't work

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt - "AndroidAnnotations needs to know where your AndroidManifest.xml is. Retrieving it through the variant allows for different AndroidManfest.xml files for each flavor. "